# Parse HTML table in php

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, html-parser

I have a database table which consists the following format of data in one column.

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="395">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="135">
                <p>Calories (kcal)<br>Energy (kj)<br>Fats<br>Carbohydrates<br>Protein<br></p>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <p>178<br>748<br>0 g<br>9.6 g<br>0.1 g<br></p>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="135">
                <p>Fiber<br>Sugars<br>Cholesterol<br>Sodium<br>Alcohol<br></p>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <p>0 g<br>-<br>0 mg<br>-<br>26.2 g<br></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make another database which has separate columns for `Calories`, `Fats`, `Carbohydrates` and `Protein`. 
To separate this data, I need to fetch data from the old database and parse it like this.

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM table";
$res = $mysqli->query($qry);

// new dom object
$dom = new DOMDocument();

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {

    $html = @$dom->loadHTML($row['columndata']);
    //the table by its tag name
    $tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
    $rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        echo $cols->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br />';
        echo $cols->item(1)->nodeValue.'<br />';
    }
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Calories (kcal)Energy (kj)FatsCarbohydratesProtein  
1787480 g9.6 g0.1 g
```

I am unable to separate the output string to have correct column values in the new database.

For example, I want to have value `178` in the `Calories` column, `0 g` in the `Fats` column, etc.

Comment: what do you mean by `parse the data based on the HTML tag`??

Comment: What output would you like?

Comment: `nodeValue` removes all the tags, you want something like Javascript's `innerHTML`. The DOMDocument API doesn't have this, you need to write it. There's a simple `get_inner_html` function in the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php

Comment: I modified the question,  I added what I need as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iterating over the child nodes of the `P` elements:

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $paragraphs = $row->getElementsByTagName('p');
    //ensure that all the text between <br> is in one text node
    $paragraphs->item(0)->normalize();
    foreach($paragraphs->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
        if ($node->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            echo $node->nodeValue . '<br/>;
        }
    }

}
```

It is important to call normalize() on the `p` element, to ensure that the texts between `br` elements are in one text node each, and not separated, eg `<p>Calories (kcal)<br>Energy (kj)<br>...</p>` will have text nodes of `Calories (kcal)` and `Energy (kj)`, not `Cal`, `ories (`, `kcal)` and so on, which they might be without normalizing.

Comment: Thanks @SWilk with your help I was able to complete this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get innerHTML of your **td** element, you may use following construction:

```
$tdElement = $row->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0);
$tdElement->ownerDocument->saveHTML( $tdElement );
```

It should return you inner html of that node as a **string**.